# Best way to slow down javascript canvas animation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas animation that I wish to slow down, it's pretty simple noise effect that moves around pixels. demo can be found here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyyjqm - I want to slow down the pixels movement/jitter.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
                 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = canvas.height = 128

resize();
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio / 1
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio / 1
    canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px'
    canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px'
}

function noise(ctx) {

    const w = ctx.canvas.width,
                h = ctx.canvas.height,
                iData = ctx.createImageData(w, h),
                buffer32 = new Uint32Array(iData.data.buffer),
                len = buffer32.length
      let i = 1

    for(; i < len;i++)

        if (Math.random() < 0.5) buffer32[i] = 0xffffffff;

        ctx.putImageData(iData, 0, 0);
}

(function loop() {
    noise(ctx);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

I've tried;

> window.setInterval('noise(ctx)',10);

but this looks so jittery and not very smooth because im setting an interval of 10 frames. What would be a better way to slow down the animation?

Appreciate any ideas! Thanks, John

Comment: Well I mean, what *does* a slowed down noise animation look like if not jittery? It only looks smooth because the framerate is so fast. Would the colors just cross-fade into the next pixel color? Would the pixels move around somehow? What would it look like?

Comment: I suppose you are correct! noise is jittery. I'm probably not explaining this very well/need to take another approach, perhaps having the pixels move around would be better! Thanks for your input, I'll look in to it now!

Comment: This comment is mostly for my reference: I made a couple of gifs to illustrate the effect I'm after (https://imgur.com/a/eMC2h) after doing this it has given me an idea for a better approach, If I space out the pixels/increase the black space it might give me a the effect I'm looking for.

Comment: Hmm, the images seem to be dark-grey on black

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach maybe can help you.

The `requestAnimationFrame` pass as parameter the currentTime which is executing, so you can get some delta `currentTime - oldTime` time in each call and if is very short not execute the noise function again, on the other hand if it has passed a considerable time execute it again, this deltaTime can de set:

something like this:

```
delta = 200;
oldTime = 0;

function loop(currentTime) {
  if(oldTime === 0) {
    oldTime = currentTime;
  }

  if((currentTime - oldTime) >= delta){
    noise(ctx);  
    oldTime = currentTime;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

here is working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyyYKa

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote some of the code to make it slightly more efficient and to hopefully get a similar effect you were looking for:

```
const w = ctx.canvas.width;
      h = ctx.canvas.height;
const   iData = ctx.createImageData(w, h);
        buffer32 = new Uint32Array(iData.data.buffer);
      len = buffer32.length;

window.setInterval('noise(ctx)',38);
function noise(ctx) {
  let i = 1

for(; i < len;i += 4)

  if (Math.random() < 0.4)
  {
    buffer32[i] = 0xffffffff;
  } else {
    buffer32[i] = 0x00000000;
  }

  ctx.putImageData(iData, 0, 0);
}

//(function loop() {
  //noise(ctx);
//    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
//})();
```

I would however recommend applying a more conventional noise algorithm such as the simplex algorithm. See example here: http://haptic-data.com/toxiclibsjs/examples/simplex-noise-canvas. It will most likely be much smoother.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this method in the past to limit how frequently the animation is updated.

```js
let frame = 0
let frameLimit = 3

draw() {
  // animation code here...
}
 
animate() {
  frame++
  if (frame % frameLimit === 0) {
    // make some changes then redraw animation
    draw()
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

Now your animation will only update every third frame. you can then easily adjust the value to speed up or slow down your animation. I don't want to claim that this is the best approach but its an alternative that I didn't see listed.